# Is Salesforce to Salesforce a good choice for a new project?

Tags: salesforce2salesforce, salesforce-to-salesforce

Just watched a Jitendra Zaa YouTube video from 2 years ago [Salesforce to Salesforce Connection within 10 Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAkaxkP3Nc4). Having to use Classic to access the Setup for this is a bit discouraging, and at 8:30 in the video there is a suggestion that support for this may end in the future.

A commenter has pointed to this [Estimate effort of a Salesforce-to-Salesforce project](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306135/estimate-effort-of-a-salesforce-to-salesforce-project) that is full of important information - **start there not here**.

So 4 questions:

1. Is there any indication that it will not be supported in the future as of March 2023?
2. From a cursory look I don't see any [Metadata types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm) for this - is setup manual only?
3. Is there a better way to do data replication (copies not external views) than this?
4. [Change Data Capture](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321199/salesforce-change-data-capture-with-cross-org-external-object) still does not support the org to org case? Though there is a comment there "This is cross-org, the external object is from a foreign org" that implies a pattern that may work (perhaps documented in [Considerations for Salesforce Connect—Cross-Org Adapter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.xorg_considerations.htm&type=5)?

Comment: I last used this in 2013 and it was [frustrating if you were using apex to automate](https://cropredysfdc.com/2014/11/17/s2s-salesforce-to-salesforce-adventures/).

Comment: Partially similar question here : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250628/is-salesforce-to-salesforce-outdated-if-so-what-is-the-best-way-to-connect-cli

Comment: Thanks cropredy and shamina - helpful.

Comment: No, it's not: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306135/estimate-effort-of-a-salesforce-to-salesforce-project . The best course of action depends on the complexity of said replication, commercial tools do well here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close this off here, this is a summary pulled from links that the commenters posted:

1. This Salesforce [Data Integration guide](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration) says "The Salesforce to Salesforce product is reaching its end of life".
2. [Estimate effort of a Salesforce-to-Salesforce project](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306135/estimate-effort-of-a-salesforce-to-salesforce-project) explains that there is no metadata API: manual setup only. **Read this for a comprehensive review of the whole subject.**
3. No specific answer. (My particular case is fairly simple so I'm thinking of generating custom Platform Events from triggers and using Apex handlers to update the remote records.)
4. Change Data Capture does support org to org via the [Salesforce Connect—Cross-Org Adapter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.xorg_considerations.htm&type=5) but looks like if you have more than 5 entities there may be a $5k a month per org charge according to this [Change Data Capture Allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_allocations.htm) and this [Salesforce Add-on Pricing](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/all-add-ons.pdf). So likely a good choice if the value delivered exceeds this cost.